# Can I insert an `if` condition inside a `case` statement?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a game. I want to give the users options depending on what they choose. My code has to be in a `case` statement:

```
puts "HA! you are in Saw 18"
puts "Lets play a deadly game! >=D"
puts "Options: hight, Who is Superman, Bake a pie "
option = gets.chomp
case option
when "hight"
  puts "Lets see your hight yo!"
  option_1 = gets.chomp
  case option_1
  when
  end
end
```

If they choose the Hight,

```
if i >= 5 ft
  puts "you may live"
else
  puts "you in trouble"
```

Any other alternatives using `case` are very welcome.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is `i`? What is `ft`?

Comment: "`Can I insert an "if" condition inside a "case" statement?`"? Really? What happened when you tried? Please try, please search, then try more. Please read "[ask]", http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can insert a condition inside the `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function from the case statement and put the if condition inside the function. Unless you have a good reason not to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, I suppose (trying not to change your code too much) you could do something like this:

```
puts "HA! you are in Saw 18"
puts "Lets play a deadly game! >=D"
puts "Options are: height, Who is Superman or Bake a pie "
option = gets.chomp

case option
when "height"
  puts "Lets see your height yo!"
  option_1 = gets.chomp.to_i
  if option_1 >= 5
    puts "you may live"
  else
    puts "you're in trouble"
  end
when "Who is Superman"
    #code
else
    #code  
end
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. sir

Comment: @SirBM great:) If you feel my answer or any other answer solved your issue or was the most useful, then feel free to accept it by clicking the grey tick for that answer so it turns green.